# Can a cyclic amine form an amide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines, amides

This is a question from the Cambridge International Examinations October/November 2017 [(pdf from papers.gceguide.com](https://papers.gceguide.com/A%20Levels/Chemistry%20(9701)/9701_w17_qp_42.pdf), [pdf via the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20190430124514/https://papers.gceguide.com/A%20Levels/Chemistry%20(9701)/9701_w17_qp_42.pdf)).

I need to understand why the secondary amine in the **serotonin** molecule does not undergo condensation reaction with $\ce{CH3COCl}$.
Because, as far as I know, there should be an amide formation for this reaction.

Here's a picture of serotonin:

[image: serotonin with highlighted NH group]

I must be lacking some information making that $\ce{NH}$ unsuitable for this reaction. And I know that the other amine and the phenol reacts with $\ce{CH3COCl}$.

Comment: Secondary amine group shown here is quite sterically hindered..Approach at Burgi-Dunitz trajectory would most probably be difficult

Comment: Did you mean lone pair of electron in N is less available for carbocation to be attacked? @YUSUFHASAN

Comment: No..I mean what you have in mind is a nucleophilic attack by NH on CH3COCl as the first step, right? So that would be retarded by steric hindrance..

Comment: Nothing to do with sterics. The lone pair on the nitrogen is delocalised into the aromatic system so is not available for nucleophilic attack. If you want to functionalise the indole-NH you generally have to formally deprotonate with strong base. Otherwise it reacts as an enamine through the 3-position.

Comment: @Waylander that is a 5 membered ring, not an aromatic ring!

Comment: @Amar30657 You need to read more about aromatic systems.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indole

Comment: @Waylander Oh, didn't know about indole, can you answer this question and I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The heterocycle in this question is indole and is aromatic. This means that the N lone pair is delocalised and not readily available for nucleophilic attack. Think of it as similar in reactivity to a secondary amide nitrogen RCONHR. Generally you need to formally deprotonate to functionalise, though there are some interesting techniques using carbonyl azoles catalysed by DBU<sup>[1]</sup> and others using aldehyde and alcohol substrates.<sup>[2]</sup> Note that 3-unsubstituted indoles react with acyl halides by F-C acylation at the 3 position.<sup>[3]</sup>

#### References:

1. Heller, S. T.; Schultz, E. E.; Sarpong, R. Chemoselective N-Acylation of Indoles and Oxazolidinones with Carbonylazoles. *Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* **2012,** *51* (33), 8304–8308 [DOI: 10.1002/anie.201203976](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201203976).
2. Maki, B. E.; Scheidt, K. A. Single-Flask Synthesis ofN-Acylated Indoles by Catalytic Dehydrogenative Coupling with Primary Alcohols. *Org. Lett.* **2009,** *11* (7), 1651–1654 [DOI: 10.1021/ol900306v](https://doi.org/10.1021/ol900306v). [PMID: 19320508](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19320508) (with free text available).
3. Okauchi, T.; Itonaga, M.; Minami, T.; Owa, T.; Kitoh, K.; Yoshino, H. A General Method for Acylation of Indoles at the 3-Position with Acyl Chlorides in the Presence of Dialkylaluminum Chloride. *Org. Lett.* **2000,** *2* (10), 1485–1487 [DOI: 10.1021/ol005841p](https://doi.org/10.1021/ol005841p).

Answer (score 5):

If you consider the lone pair on that N-atom and apply Hückel's (4n+2)π-e  rule to check aromaticity , it satisfies all the conditions. So in order to achieve aromatic-stabilisation the nitrogen's valency is no more available for condensation!

Comment: Hückel's rules should not be applied to this compound for two facts: 1. It is not a mono-cycle. 2. It is a heterocycle. It would be by far superior, at a more fundamental level, and even simpler to just state that the lone pair is delocalised. One could even show this with resonance structures, but that might be overkill.

Comment: Why can't we apply Hückel's rule?  I didn't  know that; would you please elaborate?

Comment: Related: [Is pyrene aromatic despite failing Hückel's rule?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/16562/4945) [Do lone pairs on substituents (e.g. in aniline) count towards Hückel's rule?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/16757/4945) [What is the justification for Hückel's rule?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/30927/4945) [Applying Huckel's rule to non-planar compounds](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86734/4945) My answer covers it also: **[What is Y-aromaticity? Is the trinitromethanide anion aromatic?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/34727/4945)**

Comment: Tl;dr: there are three criteria for which the rule has been observed. 1. monocyclic planar, 2. trigonal/diagonal hybridised atoms 3. (4n+2) pi electrons, n should not exceed 5. The calculations were done for $\ce{(CH)_m}$, so they *strictly* only hold for these compounds. The third criteria has been used so often (and most of the times wrong) and is incredibly popular (also wrong), that it is perceived as Hückel's rule (also wrong). It is painful to see that it is taught like this, without teaching the underlying theory, which is possibly simpler than learning about the exceptions.