# Why is 11-oxabicyclo(4.4.1)undeca-1,3,5,7,9-pentaene aromatic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromaticity

[image: 11-oxabicyclo(4.4.1)undeca-1,3,5,7,9-pentaene]

I have been told by my instructors that for a compound to be aromatic, it must be planar. In this given molecule the oxygen seems to be out of the plane of the conjugated system: how can it still be aromatic, then?

Comment: Aromaticity is a product of the conjugated bonds in a system, not of the molecule as a whole.

Comment: Please use titles that are descriptive, not cryptic. *"This compound"* is **1,6-oxido[10]annulene** (traditional name) or **11-oxabicyclo(4.4.1)undeca-1,3,5,7,9-pentaene** (PIN) and not only the oxygen bridge, but also the ring is not planar. Read about aromaticity of [1,6-methano(10)annulene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1,6-Methano(10)annulene#Aromaticity), the ideas are applicable here as well.

Comment: Related; https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/86734/applying-huckels-rule-to-non-planar-compounds/86737#86737

Comment: I point out that the Wikipedia pages on [10]-annulene and methano annulene contain conflicting info about the ring planarity. Still the less distorted and thus aromatic is the second one.

Answer (score -1):

The aromatic system should be planar. The oxygen is not part of the aromatic system.

Please note, of course, that your drawing does not capture the 3-dimensional geometry of the system. You would still have to analyze the carbon skeleton to see if it satisfied the planarity constraint enough to be aromatic.